# MIPS - Convert Day And Month (E.G 20 January) To Day Of The Year Is 20

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this assignment and i am stuck in between the codes. I am asked to collect user input day and month a year. E.g 30 May and display the equivalent as an "day of the year is 140.

This is just a part of the program that i don't understand or know how to go about it. I have been searching google for this answer but no luck. I heard i have to convert to ASCII but still don't know how to store or identify int + spring and validate January to December input  and determine the equivalent in a 365 days, assuming February is 28.

Answer (score 1):

**How to convert “days and month” to number of days of the year in MIPS.**

(This Tutorial covers conversion of string to an int.)

First thing to understand is that the input is a string and not to be treat as int. and string. Therefore, we need to convert to first two characters to int. and then treat the rest as strings. We are going to need a function that validates the month string, and return to where it left to so the program can continue execution from that point.

Converting to integer.
Example to string is: 31 January

Let’s assign a variable to the first and second character and
point the variables to the first and second character.

I will be using $t4 and $t5 respectively as follows.

lbu    $t4,0($a0)      # get next character 
lbu    $t5,1($a0)    # gets the second character

Ok. Now we have pointed our variable and have a variable for 3 and 1. What I am going to teach you need is to understand how strings are represented in a machine so you can know what to do with them.

**Representation of data in a machine**
For an example,31 January will be represented as follows in an hex code. This topic won’t cover how characters are represented in binary. Check another tutorial for this topic.

```
3  1  space J   a  n   u   a  r   y  00     characters
51 49       74   97  110  117  97  114  121  00 ASCII representation of strings
```

Refer to the ASCII Code table

It’s starts with 0 and ends with 00 which is null.

Hex-code of 0 for an integer is 48

Hex-code of 1 for an integer is 49
Hex-code of 2 for an integer is 50
Hex-code of 3 for an integer is 51

And that is what we need.

Next to convert back to an integer we need to subtract 48 ASCII codes
51 – 48 = 3 and 49 – 48 = 1

Next is to multiple the first character by 10 and add it to the second character result, this will give us result of the conversion and it is an int.

3 * 10 + 1 = 31

Can you see it’s exactly the same figure that the user inserted? But it turns to a string when he/she added month after the figure and we can't use read_int 5. Most common mistake is treating the input as integer and string instead of string.

Representation of this method is below in MIPS

```
    addi   $t4,-48       # minus first by 48 
mul    $t4,$t4,10    # multiply by 10
addi   $t5,-48       # minus second by 48
add    $t7, $t4, $t5     # sum the two into $t7
```

Now you can go ahead and use $t7 in your program, display the result or brand on equal etc. It will work since its now an integer.

The method to get the day of year is above, to see how it work in a program, it will be on my website at www.computersciencegigs.com in less than 3 weeks.

All that remains is to have label for remaining month and add the sum of previous month to the second to the last line. As January is 0, February is 31, March will be 59 etc.

Comment: i will put computersciencegigs.com up in few days. Thanks for pointing out the 0x30. Its ASCII code representations not Hex-code. And that is what i used for the method. Thanks.

Comment: got 95%. The program rejected 3 January but accepted 03 Janaury. I couldn't figure out the bug. my range code goes like this... blt    $t7,1,error   bgt    $t7,31,error. Do u have an idea why is that?